# WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView deprecated

Tags: flutter, dart, url-launcher

I am using the following code to launch URLs from my app:

```dart
WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = false;
if (!kIsWeb && Platform.isIOS) {
  // on ios, not doing this will result in a dark status bar appearance
  // which makes the content nearly invisible due to the dark background
  // https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105139#issuecomment-1143954699
  final bool isDarkMode = SchedulerBinding.instance.platformDispatcher.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(isDarkMode ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.light : SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
}
final Future<bool> result = launchUrl(uri);
// wait until user closes the browser
// https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/57536#issuecomment-931594792
do {
  await Future<void>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
} while (WidgetsBinding.instance.lifecycleState != AppLifecycleState.resumed);
WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView.automaticSystemUiAdjustment = true;
```

How can one achieve the same without `WidgetsBinding.instance.renderView` since it’s deprecated?

According to the docs, one should use `RendererBinding.renderViews` instead. But how can we find out the current `RenderView`, and is there maybe a more elegant solution?